# How to get the object file name back from an executable file

Tags: c++

Hi guys I created the object files from their respective cpp files.then made 
a common executable file in order to execute the program.

```
    g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
    g++ -Wall -g -c pts.cpp -o pts.o
    g++ -Wall -g -c rts.cpp -o rts.o

    g++ -o main main.o rts.o pts.o
```

I am not sure that it's possible to get the object files from executable file (in this case main).If it is then how ?

Comment: You want to decompile an executable?

Comment: no @NathanOliver   my intention is just to know about the object files which is responsible for executable file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The names of object files are arbitrary, you could have named them `a.o`, `b.o` and `c.o` and the result would not be different.

It is not possible to determine all of the original contents of the different object files either, since the linker discards some of the information that is present in more than one object file (e.g. inline functions).

Comment: -g adds debugging data to the ELF binaries that certainly records translation unit-related metadata.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks, missed the `-g`, updated my answer.

Comment: but can we find the dependent files for executable file?

Comment: Only if -g is used with linking. The info will be in the debug chunks in the binaries. Because so few applications really care -- just the debugger, or a handful of IDEs -- the libraries/APIs to access them are not widely documented, and you'll have to do some digging on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Since you compiled with the `-g` flag, you can use any DWARF reading utility to view information about compilation units. For instance, you can use:

```
`dwarfdump -r main`
```

Sample output:

```
.debug_aranges

COMPILE_UNIT<header overall offset = 0x00000000>:
< 0><0x0000000b>  DW_TAG_compile_unit
                    DW_AT_producer              "GNU C++ 4.9.2 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -std=c++11"
                    DW_AT_language              DW_LANG_C_plus_plus
                    DW_AT_name                  "main.cc"
                    DW_AT_comp_dir              "/home/yam/tmp/bla"
                    DW_AT_low_pc                0x004006b6
                    DW_AT_high_pc               <offset-from-lowpc>93
                    DW_AT_stmt_list             0x00000000


arange starts at 0x004006b6, length of 0x0000005d, cu_die_offset = 0x0000000b
arange end
COMPILE_UNIT<header overall offset = 0x00002a66>:
< 0><0x0000000b>  DW_TAG_compile_unit
                    DW_AT_producer              "GNU C++ 4.9.2 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -std=c++11"
                    DW_AT_language              DW_LANG_C_plus_plus
                    DW_AT_name                  "test.cc"
                    DW_AT_comp_dir              "/home/yam/tmp/bla"
                    DW_AT_low_pc                0x00400713
                    DW_AT_high_pc               <offset-from-lowpc>11
                    DW_AT_stmt_list             0x00000365
```

You can also do some simple parsing:

```
dwarfdump -r main | \
  grep 'AT_name\|AT_comp_dir' | \
  tac | sed -r 's/.*"(.*)"/\1/' | \
  ruby -e 'STDIN.readlines.map(&:strip).each_slice(2) { |s| puts File.join(*s) }'
```

Which outputs

```
/home/yam/tmp/bla/test.cc
/home/yam/tmp/bla/main.cc
```

Since your setup compiles `X.cpp` to `X.o`, you can also just replace the extensions and get the object filenames.